# Improving thermocouple response

Tags: thermocouple

I want to monitor temperatures in a DIY coffee roaster. Heat source is nichrome wire, and the beans are tumbled (6 rpm) in a stainless steel mesh cylinder that is 12" long and 4" diameter. For years I have been using an old-fashioned analog dial thermometer with a 10" probe. Now I plan to control the roast profile with a microprocessor, which will employ a K-type thermocouple. I bought a non-name 12" thermocouple probe on Amazon that turns out to be a 7mm OD stainless steel tube with the thermocouple pushed into it. Nothing affixes the junction to the tip of the tube, so it seems virtually certain that all that will be measured will be the ambient temperature at the tip of the tube. I don't think the response time will be adequate. My question -- would drilling an appropriate sized hole (~2mm) at the end of the tube to allow the junction to be exposed be the best way to make use of this? I have a lathe. Would additionally securing the tip in place with some kind of heat-tolerant cement be adviseable? The tip of the probe will be in contact with the tumbling beans. Thanks.
[image: K-type thermocouple probe]
[image]

Comment: Different form factors are for different applications. Yours is meant for liquid submersion. You probably want a bead thermocouple which will also have higher frequency response. You need a thermally conductive but high temperature adhesive. You could also try thermopiles.

Comment: I edited my original post to include a picture of the junction. I don't intend to use the probe in liquids. Would making a hole in the tip of the probe so that the junction is exposed be one solution? Thanks for your input.

Comment: No you either want a beaded thermopile or to tear the entire stainless steel casing off. That's just extra thermal mass you don't need. What is the temperature you are trying to measure? It is not clear. The air? Heating element? Coffee beans themselves?

Comment: The goal is about 425F internal temperature of the beans (the exact number depends on one's taste), which I of course cannot actually measure. I have found that if I have the tumbling beans come in contact with the probe, I can reliably obtain the desired roast, provided the heat being input in the last 4 to 5 minutes is not excessive. As the beans reach 420F or so, they are getting fairly close to combustion temperature and the specific heat has dropped substantially, so you have to throttle back significantly toward the end and add heat cautiously.

Comment: It sounds like the optimal thermocouple form factor is going to depend on how exactly this tumbler tumbles the beans. It this tumbler cylinder horizontal? Vertical? In any case, I don't recommend you drill a hole in the probe. If you need a different form factor of thermocouple you should just outright get another one.

Comment: I would keep using a stainless steel probe for cleanliness reasons. That braid around the thermocouple wire is likely fiberglass, and not something you want to get in your beans. Try to find a probe with a fine tip, and combine that with some predictive modeling to compensate for the response lag and you should be ok. You might also use a termopile looking at the beans, but that would be kind of tricky.

Comment: @Drew I think the most difficult part of the thermopile is just to find a window it can detect 8-14um wavelengths through since it can't withstand direct exposure to the 425F.

Comment: I do think I have to continue using a probe to house the thermocouple because I need the rigidity it provides. The cylinder is horizontal, and the probe extends horizontally through the center of one end and angles downward so that the tip is in the horizontal middle of the cylinder, and about 1/2" above the bottom. In that orientation, it's immersed in beans at all times, but isn't exposed directly to the heating elements under the cylinder. The more slender the probe, the less it interferes with the tumbling of the beans. I hoped to expose the joint at the tip to optimize response.

Comment: @DKNguyen I think a quartz window would work.

Comment: @Drew I was actually thinking that because I know of a cheap source of quartz windows but when looking it did not go as far as the long IR range. What were you looking at? The most optimal long IR range is 8-14um, though 5.5-14um is often used due to material cost of filters. The difference between the two is 8-14um ignores the effect of water vapour so it more accurate. Quartz seems to stops just short of 5.5um. I was actually unable to find a material that could withstand the temperatures requires with a transmission band of 8-14um.

Comment: @DKNguyen Thanks, it appears I was wrong. It does look like windows made of exotic materials such as germanium can be purchased for a fairly reasonable price however. https://www.uqgoptics.com/catalogue/optical-windows/ir-windows-uv-crystals/germanium-ge-windows-uncoated-ar-ar-ar-dlc-coated/

Comment: @Drew Yeah, but germanium won't withstand the oven's temperature on the other side. At that rate, it might just be easier to directly expose the thermopile to the oven but heatsink it to ambient. The thermopile already comes with a germanium window anyways if it is 8-14um. A different, cheaper window material if it is 5.5um-14um, but neither can directly withstand the oven temperature. If the roaster isn't completely sealed you could also perhaps place the thermopile to look into the oven. Or use a heat mirror. so it looks around the corner and isn't exposed to the hot air.

Comment: I think it's worth a shot. It's much less invasive than the thermocouple so you could always add it after the fact and compare performance.